# can I deploy a report to a report server (SSRS) without visual studio?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, reporting-services, publish, ssrs-2012

I created a report locally on my pc and now I want to push it to the clients production environment.

Do I need to ask the client to install Visual Studio in order to deploy the report?

What other way is there to get the report to this production machine, to which I can not connect to from my local machine?

Comment: Is the server in sharepoint mode or native mode? If it is native then it will need to be deployed from VS else you can just copy the report to the sharepoint folder.

Comment: when you add your answer as a comment I can't mark it as an "answer". we are running native mode so I guess there is no getting around it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We went with the option to use the command line tool RS.exe

the usage of which is explained here:
http://sqlserverselect.blogspot.nl/2010/10/rsexe-and-rss-scripts-for-automation-of.html

Answer (score 1):

You can upload a file (such as a report RDL file) using the Report Server's **Report Manager** website.

See [Upload File Page (Report Manager)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187015.aspx) for step by step details.

You will need permission access to this webpage, of course. But once you have the correct access, you can upload a report file from your local machine or a file share you have access to. No need for a VS install on the server.

Comment: He doesnt have access to the production server so this is not possible.

Comment: The user just needs access to the Report Manager website with permissions to upload reports, not the server itself. We don't know the exact setup of the OP, but for the question "Do I need to ask the client to install Visual Studio in order to deploy the report", the alternative deployment method would be Report Manager.

Comment: You may be right I have never tried to access the report manager url except when I am on the server hosting the config manager. May test this out later if I get the chance.